# HP Pavilion X2 10: Cannot boot Windows 10 efi

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, windows-10

I have this new model of detachable HP Pavilion X2 10 (n182ng). I am not able to boot into USB installer for Windows 10. I downloaded iso from Microsoft site and copied onto pendrive using Disks program, image recovery function. BIOS does not show the pendrive at all, but if Ubuntu is present on the same pendrive, its seen and boots. Secure Boot is disabled.

Please suggest how to install Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is offtopic since it relates to Windows and not Ubuntu directly, nevertheless I will answer it and redirect you to https://superuser.com/

open CMD on a Windows machine and use DISKPART.

- list disk
- select disk 1 (or the intended disk, be careful because external drives and local drives are listed also)
- clean
- create partition primary
- active
- assign
- format fs=fat32 quick
- exit

Open Windows 10 .iso file and copy all files to your USB pendrive. It should boot normally with or withour UEFI enabled. (As a personal recommendation I always enable UEFI)